# Console Application Customizer v1.0.0.2

Tags: c#, console

**GetBootstrap v1.0.0.2** a console customizer update from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65329/console-application-customizer-bootstrap-style)

Please give me tips, request and suggestion for my future updates. 
*(I update every 2 weeks)*

Sample Preview
[image]

The following code contains the `Write()`, `WriteLine()` and `Typewriter` effect of the console.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetBootstrap.Styles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Project: Console-Bootstrap v1.0.0.2 Beta
    /// Description: Use to provide a customize console application. 
    /// Developer: Leonel Sarmiento
    /// Contact: ditleonel@outlook.com
    /// </summary>
    public static class Bootstrap 
    {
        public static void Write(string value, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle)
        {
            Styler.SetStyle(bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle);
            Console.Write(value);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        public static void Write(string value, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, int minDelay, int maxDelay)
        {
            Styler.SetStyle(bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle);
            Typewriter.Write(value, minDelay, maxDelay);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        public static void Write(string format, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, params object[] arg)
        {
            Styler.SetStyle(bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle);
            Console.Write(format, arg);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        public static void Write(string format, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, int minDelay, int maxDelay, params object[] arg)
        {
            Styler.SetStyle(bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle);
            Typewriter.Write(string.Format(format,arg), minDelay, maxDelay);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string value, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle)
        {
            Write(value, bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string value, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, int minDelay, int maxDelay)
        {
            Write(value, bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle, minDelay, maxDelay);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string format, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, params object[] arg)
        {
            Write(format, bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle, arg);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string format, BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle, int minDelay, int maxDelay, params object[] arg)
        {
            Write(format, bootstrapType, bootstrapStyle, minDelay, maxDelay, arg);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }

    public static class Typewriter
    {
        public static void Write(string value, int minDelay, int maxDelay)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int c = 0; c < value.Count(); c++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(random.Next(minDelay, maxDelay));
                Console.Write(value.Substring(c,1));
            }
        }

        public static void WriteLine(string value, int minDelay, int maxDelay)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int c = 0; c < value.Count(); c++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(random.Next(minDelay, maxDelay));
                if (c != value.Count() - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(value.Substring(c, 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value.Substring(c, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Styler
    {
        public static void SetStyle(BootstrapType bootstrapType, BootstrapStyle bootstrapStyle)
        {
            switch (bootstrapType)
            {
                case BootstrapType.Success:
                    if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    }
                    break;
                case BootstrapType.Info:
                    if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    }
                    break;
                case BootstrapType.Warning:
                    if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    }
                    break;
                case BootstrapType.Danger:
                    if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum BootstrapStyle
    {
        None = 0,
        Alert = 1
    }

    public enum BootstrapType
    {
        Default = 0,
        Success = 1,
        Info = 2,
        Warning = 3,
        Danger = 4
    }
}
```

- **Version:** v1.0.0.2
- **Updates:**

  - Update mappings and code structures (Thanks to [ChrisWue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/30346/chriswue))
- [Download Link](http://1drv.ms/1sQYUVl)

Comment: In your if elses in your switch, you don't need elses if the exact same code is in the if, for example: vConsole.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify `TypeWriter.WriteLine` by implementing it in terms of `TypeWriter.Write`:

```
public static void WriteLine(string value, int minDelay, int maxDelay)
{
    Write(value, minDelay, maxDelay);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

---

Do you really need a `new Random()` in every call to `Write`? Why not create a single `Random` object per class and reuse that in `random.Next(...)` calls?

---

Both branches of this `if` set the foreground to green no matter what:

> ```
> if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
> {
>     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
>     Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
> }
> else
> {
>     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
> }
> ```

You can simplify to:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
if (bootstrapStyle == BootstrapStyle.Alert)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
}
```

The same goes for all the `case` statements in the `switch (bootstrapType)`.

---

When using enums, don't assign their values if you don't really need to. This is simpler and better:

```
public enum BootstrapStyle
{
    None,
    Alert
}
```