# Console Application Customizer - GetBootstrap v2.7.0

Tags: c#, console

**GetBootstrap v2.7.0** Update from [**GetBootstrap v2.5**](https://github.com/devlsarmiento/GetBootstrap)

I add a progress bar feature in my console application customizer and update the `#region` grouping and convert the `switch` statement to `Dictionary` that suggested in the last [**version**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/70270/29034).

[image: v2.7.0]

For now I need help in reviewing my codes in `ProgressBar.cs`. You can also review my source code and contribute in my [**GitHub**](https://github.com/devlsarmiento/GetBootstrap) if you want. [**DOWNLOAD GetBootstrap v2.7.0**](https://github.com/devlsarmiento/GetBootstrap/releases/)

My objective is to create a progress bar that can be modify to 4 different size *(small, normal, medium, and large)* and change color.

This is the best code I can make. Any Suggestion?

**ProgressBar.cs**

```
public class ProgressBar
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
    public ProgressBarSize Size { get; set; }
    float _Calculation { get; set; }

    public ProgressBar()
    {
        Max = 100;
        Value = 0;
        Color = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Size = ProgressBarSize.Normal;
    }

    public void Increment(int value)
    {
        Value += value;

        if (Value <= Max)
        {  
            SetUpProgressBar();

            WriteProgressBar();
        }

    }

    private void WriteProgressBar()
    {
        ProgressBarSize size = Size;
        object valueSize = Convert.ChangeType(size, size.GetTypeCode());

        int position = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= _Calculation * Value; i++)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = Color;
            Console.CursorLeft = position++;
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        for (int i = Value; i <= (int)valueSize + 1; i++)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.CursorLeft = position++;
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        WriteProgressBarStatus((int)valueSize);
    }

    private void WriteProgressBarStatus(int p)
    {
        Console.CursorLeft = p + 5;
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write(Value + " of " + Max);
    }

    private void SetUpProgressBar()
    {
        ProgressBarSize size = Size;
        object valueSize = Convert.ChangeType(size , size.GetTypeCode());

        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.CursorLeft = (int)valueSize + 2;
        Console.Write("|");
        Console.CursorLeft = 1;
        _Calculation = ((int)valueSize + 0.0f) / Max;
    }
}

public enum ProgressBarSize
{
    Small = 20,
    Normal = 30,
    Medium = 40,
    Large = 60
}
```

Comment: It looks like this project isn't available anymore? I think this was a good effort, any thoughts on why you aren't sharing this any longer?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe I am sad to say that I lost the source code of this version, but I have plan to rebuild this soon.

Comment: oh ok, thx - be sure to post it on git or any other site :)

Comment: @YvesSchelpe I just updated the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normally a good idea to separate data from behavior as this way we follow [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) guidelines.

I recommend creating a `ProgressBar` object and maybe a `ProgressBarOperationService` or the like with the behavior.

The `ProgressBarOperationService` would receive the `ProgressBar` that needs the operation in all its methods.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need here is a Constructor that assigns values to private properties.

> ```
> public int Max { get; set; }
> public int Value { get; set; }
> public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
> public ProgressBarSize Size { get; set; }
> float _Calculation { get; set; }
>
> public ProgressBar()
> {
>     Max = 100;
>     Value = 0;
>     Color = ConsoleColor.Blue;
>     Size = ProgressBarSize.Normal;
> }
> ```

Your `Max` variable shouldn't be public, and should be a constant variable.  assuming that you are creating this progress bar from scratch you want 0 as the min and 100 as the max meaning 0% and 100%  but you don't have a `Min` you have `Value` and that is fine.

---

Another thing is your structure for this class.

Personally I would only have 3 outward facing methods

1. Constructor
2. Start
3. Stop

and then some Events

1. On_Start
2. On_Stop
3. On_Finish
4. {Some Event based on progression}

Comment: Hmn... if i set the `Max`to private the user will not able to change it's value? *-"The objective of the `ProgressBar` is to get the count the process and increment every process that finished."*

Comment: you shouldn't Create the Progress bar until you know what you are tracking the progress of, so you should just pass that value in through the constructor, that is the right way to do it.