# Console Application Customization - GetBootstrap v2.8.6.19

Tags: c#, console

It's been a long time since my last post. I decided to continue this little project and tried to debug the [GetBootstrap v2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77052/console-application-customizer-getbootstrap-v2-7-0). I found out that the progress bar that I create is not working properly when the size of console buffer is changes. so I decide to rewrite it again.

Below, the progress task is to rewrite itself from the last call of `ProgressBar.Write()` and `Increment()` its value. I also use thread lock to prevent other `Console.Write()` to overlap each other. Is there any better way to improve this code? By the way, you can download the source code in [GetBootstrap v2.8.6.19](https://github.com/devlsarmiento/GetBootstrap/releases/tag/getbootstrap-2.8.6.19) to have a better view.

[image]

#### ProgressBar.cs

```
namespace System.Extensions
{
    public class ProgressBar
    {
        private int _cwidth;
        private int _cheight;
        private int _csrtop;
        private int _csrleft;
        private int _progwidth;
        private int _value = 0;
        private int _maxvalue;
        private float _width = 50;
        private bool _showPercent = true;
        private bool _showSeparator = true;

        public int Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }
        public int MaxValue { get => _maxvalue; set => _maxvalue = value; }

        public float Width
        {
            get => _width; set
            {
                if (value > 100)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Width must not greater than to 100");
                }
                else if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Width must not less than to 0");
                }
                _width = value;
            }
        }

        public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        public ConsoleColor ProgressColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        public ConsoleColor SeparatorColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        public bool ShowPercent { get => _showPercent; set => _showPercent = value; }
        public bool ShowSeparator { get => _showSeparator; set => _showSeparator = value; }

        public ProgressBar(int maxValue = 100)
        {
            _maxvalue = maxValue;
        }

        public void Write()
        {
            _cwidth = (int)(((Console.BufferWidth - (_showPercent ? 7 : 0)) / 100f) * _width);
            _cheight = Console.BufferHeight;
            _csrtop = Console.CursorTop;
            _csrleft = Console.CursorLeft;

            _progwidth = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _cwidth - _csrleft; i++)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = SeparatorColor;
                Console.Write(_showSeparator ? "_" : " ");
                _progwidth++;
            }
        }

        public void WriteLine()
        {
            Write();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public void Increment(int increment = 1)
        {
            lock (Bootstrap._threads)
            {
                _value += increment;
                if (_value <= _maxvalue)
                {
                    int _cursortop = Console.CursorTop;
                    int _cursorleft = Console.CursorLeft;

                    Console.CursorTop = _csrtop;
                    Console.CursorLeft = _csrleft;
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ProgressColor;

                    float progress = (_value / (float)_maxvalue) * 100f;
                    float pbwidth = (_progwidth / 100f) * progress;
                    for (int i = 0; i < pbwidth; i++)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = SeparatorColor;
                        Console.Write(_showSeparator ? "_" : " ");
                    }
                    Console.ResetColor();

                    if (_showPercent)
                    {
                        Console.CursorLeft = _cwidth;
                        Console.WriteLine($" {progress.ToString("0.00")}%");
                    }

                    Console.CursorTop = _cursortop;
                    Console.CursorLeft = _cursorleft;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Grammar in the exception messages: `"Width must not greater than to 100"` should be `"Width must not be greater than 100"`, and `"Width must not less than to 0"` should be `"Width must not be less than 0"`.

Comment: Strangely your code was better in the previous version 2.7 three years ago than it is now.

Comment: @t3chb0t Maybe because I used a lot of private fields, someone told me that I should not give direct access to a member variables and use properties for accessing it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bugs

There's a fair amount of bugs in your code. The 'happy path' works,  but it's easy to break something. Especially when you're writing library-level code it's useful to occasionally look at your code with a 'how can I break this' mindset.

- `Write` and `WriteLine` only draw an empty progress bar, without percentage label, even when `Value` is higher than zero.
- `Increment` won't draw the progress bar if `Value` is larger than `MaxValue`. Use `Math.Min(Value, MaxValue)` instead of an `if` statement.
- Neither `Value`'s setter nor `Increment` protect `Value` from becoming negative, so you can end up with a negative percentage. In some cases that can also cause the percentage label to wrap around to the next line.
- Setting `MaxValue` to 0 results in NaN% or in some cases -∞%. You should either enforce that `MaxValue` must be larger than the minimum value (0), or take these edge-cases into account in your redraw logic.
- Calling `Increment` without having called `Write` or `WriteLine` does not draw a progress bar, only a percentage label.
- Calling `Write` (instead of `WriteLine`) with `ShowPercent` enabled does not leave the cursor position in a proper position: the next thing that is written is written in the percentage label area.
- The redraw logic does not take value decrements (negative increments, or just assigning a lower value to `Value`) into account.

### Other notes

- `Write` and `WriteLine` must be called first, to set the progress bar location, and then `Increment` must be called to redraw it. This means duplicate drawing code, and it's easy to use incorrectly (calling `Increment` before `Write`, or not calling `Write` at all). Why not combine all these into a single `Draw` method?
- Why is the redraw method called `Increment`? Why does it combine drawing with adjusting the value? The value can already be adjusted via the `Value` property, and there are various other properties that affect rendering too.
- `Width` is actually a percentage - setting it to 50 makes the progress bar half as wide as the console window. This isn't clear from the name, so I would add a little explanation (comment) there. You may also want to explain that the bar doesn't resize when the console window is resized.
- It's good that you're taking thread-safety seriously, but I'm not sure how much protection you're hoping to gain with that lock, since other code (outside your control) can still freely access `Console`. Creating a thread-safe wrapper around `Console` and documenting that all console interaction should be done via that wrapper should be more robust. It could offer atomic write methods that take a position and color, so calling code doesn't need to do any locking itself.
- There's no need for explicit backing fields for properties that don't do anything special in their getter and setter. If you do need an explicit backing field (such as `_width`) then personally I'd put it close to its associated property, not grouped together with other private fields.
- `$" {progress.ToString("0.00")}%"` can be written more succinctly as `$" {progress:0.00}%"`.
- There's no need to set console colors inside those drawing loops. In fact, there's no need for loops at all - preparing a string (or char array) beforehand allows you to reduce the number of `Console.Write` calls, which should be faster.
- Abbreviations like `csrtop` may be slightly faster to write, but they don't improve the readability of the code. Just write `cursorTop`.
- You use a leading underscore for private fields, but sometimes also for local variables. Being inconsistent generally makes code harder to read (that is, it takes more time and work to understand).
- Instead of implicitly using 0 as minimum value, you may want to add a `MinValue` property.
- Do you have a specific reason for restricting `Value` to integers?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: each individual console operation is safe, but the progress bar redrawing as a whole is not. What if another thread writes some text when the progress bar has been redrawn, but the console position hasn't been restored yet? Or in-between two `Console.Write` calls?

Comment: that's true, you're right!