# Console colorizer

Tags: c#, recursion, console, xml

To be able to apply various colors to the console I created a `ConosoleColorizer`. It's really simple. It just takes an XML and renders it to the console with the colors specified.

The element names are actually optional and can be any names. They are only required to parse the XML. What matters are the attribute and color names. I didn't know how to solve it with less effort without *inventing* a new markup.

```
internal class ConsoleColorizer
{
    public static void Render(string xml)
    {
        Render(XElement.Parse(xml).Nodes());
    }

    public static void Render(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes)
    {
        Render(xNodes, null, null);
    }

    private static void Render(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes, ConsoleColor? lastForegroundColor, ConsoleColor? lastBackgroundColor)
    {
        foreach (var xChildNode in xNodes)
        {
            var xElement = xChildNode as XElement;
            if (xElement != null)
            {
                Render(
                    xElement.Nodes(),
                    SetForegroundColor(xElement),
                    SetBackgroundColor(xElement)
                );
            }
            else
            {
                RestoreForegroundColor(lastForegroundColor);
                RestoreBackgroundColor(lastBackgroundColor);
                Console.Write(((XText)xChildNode).Value);
            }
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    private static ConsoleColor? SetForegroundColor(XElement xElement)
    {
        var foregroundColor = (ConsoleColor)0;
        if (Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(xElement.Attribute("fg")?.Value, true, out foregroundColor))
        {
            return Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static ConsoleColor? SetBackgroundColor(XElement xElement)
    {
        var backgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)0;
        if (Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(xElement.Attribute("bg")?.Value, true, out backgroundColor))
        {
            return Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void RestoreForegroundColor(ConsoleColor? consoleColor)
    {
        if (consoleColor.HasValue)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor.Value;
        }
    }

    private static void RestoreBackgroundColor(ConsoleColor? consoleColor)
    {
        if (consoleColor.HasValue)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = consoleColor.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var xml = @"<line>Hallo <color fg=""yellow"">colored</color> console! <color fg=""darkred"" bg=""darkgray"">These are <color fg=""white"" bg=""blue"">nested</color> colors</color>.</line>";
ConsoleColorizer.Render(xml);
```

[image: ConsoleColorizer]

Comment: *Gets memories of QBASIC looking at that white-on-blue and red-on-gray text*

Comment: @Mat'sMug the colors are purely coincidental but now I see it too ;-]

Comment: You might be interested in this related question & project. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/70270/41243

Comment: @RubberDuck that project is exactly how I didn't want it to be - and I had before ;-) I prefer to use a html/xml like syntax for a template to render a line with multiple styles rather then several lines of _Something.Write(...)_ I downloaded the source and saw it ;-] however the Idea with predefined styles is good so I'll probably add it to my colorizer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question looks mostly good to me, but it could be enhanced a little bit.

#### `private static void Render()`

The call to [`Console.ResetColor();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.resetcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't belong here because it isn't necessary to reset the colors each time.

Remarks from link above:

> The foreground and background colors are restored to the colors that existed when the current process began.

So it is sufficient to call that method at the end of the `Render(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes)` method.

The passed in `lastForegroundColor` and `lastBackgroundColor` are only needed if one of the childnodes is a `XElement` so if we extract the rendering of a `XElement` to a separate method, the former `Render()` method would look after renaming to `RenderInternal()` like so

```
private static void RenderInternal(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes)
{
    foreach (var xChildNode in xNodes)
    {
        var xElement = xChildNode as XElement;
        if (xElement != null)
        {
            RenderInternal(xElement);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(((XText)xChildNode).Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The extracted `RenderInternal(XElement)` method could look like so, if we just use the current implemented methods

```
private static void RenderInternal(XElement xElement)
{
    ConsoleColor lastForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    ConsoleColor lastBackgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

    SetForegroundColor(xElement);
    SetBackgroundColor(xElement);

    RenderInternal(xElement.Nodes());

    RestoreForegroundColor(lastForegroundColor);
    RestoreBackgroundColor(lastBackgroundColor);

}
```

which removes the strangeness of a `SetXxx` method to return something. But hey, I just don't like how this is looking. So let us introduce a `struct ConsoleColors` to hold both the Foreground- and the Backgroundcolor like so

```
public struct ConsoleColors
{
    public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor { get;}
    public ConsoleColor ForegroundColor { get;}
    public static ConsoleColors Current
    {
        get
        {
            return new ConsoleColors(Console.ForegroundColor, Console.BackgroundColor);
        }
    }
    
    public ConsoleColors(ConsoleColor foregroundColor, ConsoleColor backgroundColor)
        :this()
    {
        ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

and add a method which sets a `ConsoleColors` struct like so

```
private static void SetColors(ConsoleColors colors)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = colors.ForegroundColor;
    Console.BackgroundColor = colors.BackgroundColor;
}
```

and refactor the `RenderInternal(XElement)` method like so

```
private static void RenderInternal(XElement xElement)
{
    ConsoleColors savedColors = ConsoleColors.Current;

    SetForegroundColor(xElement);
    SetBackgroundColor(xElement);

    RenderInternal(xElement.Nodes());

    SetColors(savedColors);
}
```

which looks better, but still has the calls `SetForegroundColor` and `SetBackgroundColor`. So we can add an extension method which turns a `XElement` to a `ConsoleColors` so we can use the `SetColors` method.

```
public static ConsoleColors ToConsoleColors(this XElement xElement, string foregroundAttributeName = "fg", string backgroundAttributeName = "bg")
{
    if (xElement == null) { return ConsoleColors.Current; }

    var foregroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(xElement.Attribute(foregroundAttributeName)?.Value, true, out foregroundColor);

    var backgroundColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
    Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(xElement.Attribute(backgroundAttributeName)?.Value, true, out backgroundColor);

    return new ConsoleColors(foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
}
```

which leads to

```
    internal class ConsoleColorizer
    {
        public static void Render(string xml)
        {
            Render(XElement.Parse(xml).Nodes());
        }

        public static void Render(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes)
        {
            RenderInternal(xNodes);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        private static void RenderInternal(IEnumerable<XNode> xNodes)
        {
            foreach (var xChildNode in xNodes)
            {
                var xElement = xChildNode as XElement;
                if (xElement != null)
                {
                    RenderInternal(xElement);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(((XText)xChildNode).Value);
                }
            }
        }
        private static void RenderInternal(XElement xElement)
        {
            ConsoleColors savedColors = ConsoleColors.Current;

            SetColors(xElement.ToConsoleColors());

            RenderInternal(xElement.Nodes());

            SetColors(savedColors);
        }

        private static void SetColors(ConsoleColors colors)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = colors.ForegroundColor;
            Console.BackgroundColor = colors.BackgroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestions. Together with @RobH's review they make it much more reliable and prittier ;-)

Comment: There is a reason why I put the `Enum.TryParse` inside an `if`. The `TryParse` will reset the `out` variable, see [`result = default(TEnum);` at Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,7ef4c46032079d2b) so the default value won't be the current `ConsoleColor.ForegroundColor` but `Black` (0) if an attribute wasn't there - but I can fix it ;-)

Comment: I missed that piece. Good catch

Answer (score 3):

This is dangerous: `((XText)xChildNode)` you can't make the guarantee that the child node will be a text node. For example, say that I have this console message:

```
var message = 
@"<text>
    hallo
    <!-- tag name is irrelevant, it's all in the attribute -->
    <color fg=""yellow"">colored</color> 
    console!
</text>";
ConsoleColorizer.Render(message);
```

That's an `InvalidCastException` right there so only part of the message will be printed out.

---

`var backgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)0;` is odd, it's about the only place I don't use `var`... `ConsoleColor backgroundColor;` is much clearer.